# How do I go about reverting a Community edit?

Tags: support, suggested-edits

What are the options I have, to revert a community edit? I don't want to simply edit my question; I was looking for something similar to a roll-back option where the approvers are notified that I wish to reject their proposed edits.

I might be missing out on some obvious existing way to do it but help would be appreciated.

[Case in point](https://physics.stackexchange.com/posts/75052/revisions) (3rd edit changed the question to something that doesn't make sense any more)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a rollback option, but it doesn't notify anyone, just creates the reverse edit. You can find it on the bar for the second (and first) revision of the post.

A Community edit is just one that was suggested by an anonymous user.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Actually, I don't mind the first and second edits. I'd like to retain them. I can't find 'rollback' for the community edit.

Comment: @mehfoos The rollback option on a revision rollbacks _to_ that revision. The reason the Community one doesn't have the option is because it's the newest one

Comment: Ah, I see! how silly of me!